# How to detect an item on ground?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I searched on internet including this site, people said that it worked for them.

I wanna detect a paper laying on the ground and if there is a paper on the ground it runs an command.

I tried this command but it doesn't work.

```
/execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:paper",Count:1b,tag:{onGround:1b}}}] run say test
```

Update: More specifically how to make this command:

```
/execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:paper"}}] at @s run say test
```

Work only on papers that are on ground?

Comment: I'll just specify: Java Edition 1.16.4

Answer (score 1):

You miscapitalized `OnGround` as `onGround`.

Correct:

```
{OnGround:1b}
```

Comment: Oh, well then...